# use BinDiff to compare two chosen functions

Tags: bin-diffing, tool-bindiff

Is it possible to use BinDiff to get the comparison score between two **specific** functions from the databases? By default BinDiff will automagically match functions, and then only output the comparison score between the function matches that it finds.

I have an a priora candidate function match `[func_i from database A, func_j from database B]` and I want to get the BinDiff comparison score of this pair.

Bonus points if this can be batched and run from the command line, where I can provide a list of function pairs and get the BinDiff comparison score for each pair.